# Autofill Dynamic Range Last Row and Last Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, autofill, vba

I have a workbook containing multiple sheets of varying sizes. I want to add a total column after the last row and copy the formula across all columns. I have defined the last row and column and the formula appears as expected in the correct place but I receive an error when trying to fill across. How do I correctly reference both dynamic cells for the fill? I'm just using a single sheet for now for testing but will eventually be looping through all the sheets in the book.

```
Sub Addtotals()

    Dim Bord As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim LCol As Long
    Dim frmcell As Range

    Set Bord = Sheets("Borders")
    With Bord
    '--> Define last rows and columns
        LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LCol = .Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    '--> Add Total text to first column
        .Range("A" & LRow).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell = "Total"

    '--> Add formula to next column
        Set frmcell = Range("B" & LRow + 1)
        frmcell.Formula = "=sum(B2:B" & LRow & ")"

    '--> Fill formula across range
        frmcell.Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(frmcell & LCol), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Addtotals()
    Dim Bord As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long

    Set Bord = Sheets("Borders")
    With Bord
    '--> Define last rows and columns
        LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        LCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    '--> Add Total text to first column
        .Range("A" & LRow).Value = "Total"

    '--> Fill formula across range
        .Range("B" & LRow & ":" & _
        Split(Cells(, LCol).Address, "$")(1) & LRow).Formula = _
        "=Sum(B2:B" & LRow - 1 & ")"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. What's the function of `split`?

Comment: `Split(Cells(, LCol).Address, "$")(1)` Returns the Column Name From Column Number :)

Comment: I guess I would use split to select the final column for Copy and Pasting to a new sheet as well?

Comment: Yup :) provided `LCol` contains the right Column Number for the last column