# Dynamic first and last row of a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am surprised there's no answer for this. I have read [Setting Dynamic Ranges in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376174/setting-dynamic-ranges-in-vba) and [Selecting Dynamic Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412060/selecting-dynamic-range?rq=1) and [Autofill Dynamic Range Last Row and Last Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753925/autofill-dynamic-range-last-row-and-last-column) and [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e626eba2-8019-48e9-9827-3d98a3ad64f9/excel-vba-select-range-dynamically?forum=exceldev)

I have multiple, distinct ranges on a sheet with varying sizes. I am trying to subtotal `column L`. I can do it using a hardcoded sum (via `subtotal` variable) but I want to insert a formula into the cell instead. This requires knowing the starting and end rows for each range. My code almost works. It fails when the range only consists of one row. Even so, I feel there's gotta be a smarter way to do this.

How does one determine the start and end row of a range on a sheet filled with multiple ranges?

```
For i = 2 To j

    If .Cells(i + 1, "L") = "" And .Cells(i + 2, "L") = "" Then
        b = .Cells(i - 1, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    End If

    subtotal = subtotal + .Cells(i, "L").Value2
    If .Cells(i, 1) = "" And .Cells(i - 1, "B") <> "" Then
        If .Cells(i - 1, "K") = 0 Then
            .Cells(i, "K").Value2 = "Check Payment"
            'Set sumRng = .Range(.Cells(b, "L"), .Cells(i - 1, "L"))
            .Cells(i, "L").Formula = "=sum(L" & b & ":L" & i - 1 & ")"
            .Cells(i - 1, "L").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            total = total + subtotal
            subtotal = 0
        ElseIf .Cells(i - 1, "K") = "Checking" Then
            .Cells(i, "K").Value2 = "EFT Payment"
            'Set sumRng = .Range(.Cells(b, "L"), .Cells(i - 1, "L"))
            .Cells(i, "L").Formula = "=sum(L" & b & ":L" & i - 1 & ")"
            .Cells(i - 1, "L").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            total = total + subtotal
            subtotal = 0
        End If
    End If
Next
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the column like this:

```
For i = 2 To mySheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If Range("B" & i).Value <> vbNullString Then
        If Range("B" & i - 1).Value = vbNullString Then
            j = i
        End If
    Else
        If Range("B" & i - 1).Value <> vbNullString And Range("B" & i - 1).Formula <> "=SUM(B" & j & ":B" & i - 2 & ")" Then
            Range("B" & i).Formula = "=SUM(B" & j & ":B" & i - 1 & ")"
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: The formula produced is `=SUM(L:L3)` also getting a `type mismatch` error when it loops to next row. Error on line 7 of your code.

Comment: Try adding j = 1 before the loop. I assumed you had blank lines above your data as in your screencap

Answer (score 1):

This uses Match to skip chunks and as such the number or loops are less

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim b As Long
    b = 2

    Do Until b = .Rows.Count

        Dim x As Variant
        x = .Evaluate("Match(True, Index(" & .Range(.Cells(b, "l"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "l")).Address & " <> """",),0)")
        If Not IsError(x) Then
            b = b + x - 1
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

        x = .Evaluate("Match(True, Index(" & .Range(.Cells(b, "l"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "l")).Address & " = """",),0)")
        Dim i As Long
        i = b + x - 1

        .Cells(i, "l").Formula = "=sum(L" & b & ":L" & i - 1 & ")"

        b = i + 2
     Loop
End With
```